# Selenium get Element with label

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, label

i'm trying to get the texts (answers) next to the radiobuttons, to compare them with the correct answer.

Here is the html part:

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
    <td class="middle" width="15">
        <input name="multiple_choice_result" value="0" id="0" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="middle">
       <label for="0">FIRST ANSWER</label>  // This text
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="middle" width="15">
        <input name="multiple_choice_result" value="1" id="1" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="middle">
      <label for="1">SECOND ANSWER</label>  //This text
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class="middle" width="15">
        <input name="multiple_choice_result" value="2" id="2" type="radio">
    </td>
    <td class="middle">
        <label for="2">THIRD ANSWER</label>  //This text
    </td>
 </tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: What is your problem and what have you tried to do?

Comment: where is script which you have written to get text?

Answer (score 1):

Use below Xpath:-

```
//label[contains(.,'ANSWER')]
```

Note:- Above xpath will return 3 elements so I am using List

```
List<WebElement> allanswer = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'ANSWER')]"));
for(WebElement answer: allanswer){
        System.out.println(answer.getText());
}
```

If you want any particular answer then use:-

```
//label[contains(.,'FIRST ANSWER')]
```

Replace FIRST with SECOND OR THIRD according to your need

```
String answer =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'FIRST ANSWER')]")).getText();
```

Hope it will help you :)